# express.js - dynamic pageloads via ajax

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

ok i'm that far:

```
app.get('/mypartial', function (req. res) {
    res.render('mypartial', {layout: false, data: data});
});
```

this renders out my jade with the data and sends it as html to the client

now i need to fetch this via js and to render it out using

```
$('#idofparentelementofyourpartial').html(responseHTML);
```

so i would need something like:

```
//// Pseudocode
var locat = window.location.pathname;
on locat change{

    prevent default // because i want to use the ajax call (not standart browser call)

    ajax({
        url: locat,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: $('#idofparentelementofyourpartial').html(data);
    });
}
```

the strange thing is that "layout: false" still trys to render something: i would expect that it just puts stuff into the dom

Comment: Express version? Because there's no more `layout` in 3.

Comment: express 3.2 ... ok do you know how to do this in  > 3.xx

Comment: If you're using Jade, you're probably doing `extends myLayout` in `mypartial.jade` right? Jade doesn't support conditional extends, but you could split this into two files and `include` the one. And then use the included one in your render call. I hope this makes sense to you.

Comment: yes thats what i actually do, but this is no ajax - because everything thats included "around" gets rerendered, too =/

Comment: Just render the thing you normally include. Say you have `layout.jade`, `home.jade` and `box.jade`. `home` extends `layout` and `home` includes `box`. If you `render()` `box`, there's nothing around, because it doesn't know about `layout` or `home`.

Comment: if that wld be an answere and it works ill give you the accepted answere ;)

Comment: ok sry missunderstood - i want to render the inner slide while the others remain around, not updating/rerendering/changing ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a look at jQuery [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to load partial html into a defined container.

```
ajax({
    url: locat,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: $('#idofparentelementofyourpartial').html(data);
});
```

Datatype JSON is not what you want.

Comment: this... makes sence ^^ i'll take a look at the partitial ;)